# Why doesn't jQuery's document.ready from a dynamic append() wait for external scripts/styles?

Tags: jquery, file, document-ready

I'm having an issue with jQuery's document.ready trigger function. I'm not sure if this is due to jQuery or due to the browsers' behavior but here's what happens: when you try to dynamically load a script using the .append() method and also set a handler for document.ready(), the document.ready() event will be triggered before the external script/css file will be loaded. This does not apply for script/css files that are on the same domain - if they are on the same domain the document.ready trigger will wait for them to load.

Here's a sample of code that shows the error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var html = '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>'
                     + '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {alert(typeof jQuery.ui);})</' + 'script>';

            $('body').append(html);
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of getting an alert with "object" we get an alert with "undefined".

Thank you and kind regards.

EDIT: Someone else experienced a similar problem and they used a solution that first loads the external scripts and then loads the HTML/plain JS. The link is: http://snipplr.com/view/43449/load-external-scripts-first-for-injected-dom-html-content/. Anyway, I'm not happy with this solution as it implies several changes in the code and I'm not sure if it's 100% reliable on all browsers.

Comment: Your DOM is already ready when you call that, it doesn't change its status after that regardless of what you do?

Comment: Then how come it works when you try to include a local script (from the same domain as the page)? Also, isn't there an workaround for such a situation (like invalidating the document ready state)?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use onload, instead of document ready?

Comment: To which DOM element should I apply the onload trigger? As I know, the window.onload event is trigger only once.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Loading with the DOM**

As Niklas said, your dom is already ready.

You may apply this method

```
jQuery.getScript("url",function () { /* on success.. do this */ });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

http://jsfiddle.net/4crRw/

**2. Adding them together**

http://jsfiddle.net/4crRw/2/

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var alertWhenDone = function (requiredObjects, callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.required = requiredObjects;
        this.addDone = function (label) {
            // remove it from the list
            this.required.splice(this.required.indexOf(label),1);
            if (this.required.length === 0)
            {
                this.callback();
            }
        };
        return this;
    };
    var alertdone = alertWhenDone(['ui','swfloader','font'], function () {
        alert('done');
    });
    jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js',
        function () {
            alertdone.addDone('ui');
        });

    jQuery.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js',
        function () {
            alertdone.addDone('swfloader');
        });

    jQuery.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.0.19/webfont.js',
        function () {
            alertdone.addDone('font');
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but unfortunately the solution described in the article from squidoo.com doesn't seem to handy/elegant as it's based on a trivial check if a specific element is loaded and it requires a hard-coding of a time threshold in order to avoid an infinite loop. So, the main disadvantage of this solution is that it requires an implementation for each file you load and if there are many of them the code will become messy.

Comment: Ok, editted it, this should work better, I've also added a jsfiddle for you

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with getScript but the problem comes when you have multiple scripts. When I first ran over this issue I had a CSS file and a JS file that were required to be loaded. Again, the solution for this would be to use something like jQuery.getScript("script.js", function() {jQuery.getScript("style.css", function() { /*...*/ })}). As you can see in this example, if you will have more than one script/css file you will end up with a confusing code.

Comment: I see that someone implemented a solution for loading multiple scripts at once and having a single onLoad event for all: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/jgjHy/. This could be handy but, still, I was looking for a ready/load trigger that will be called no matter on how many scripts are left to be loaded.

Comment: And, lastly, it's not clear to me why document.ready works when calling local JS/CSS files and it doesn't when calling remote JS/CSS files (I've tested and it doesn't have anything to do with the loading time).

Comment: Ok, I added a similar one, but by hand. The defferred one is probably nicer.

Comment: Razvan: it's not about loading time, but about loading timing. If you call then dynamically they are added after the domReady event.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in putting this script together. I appreciate your help on this matter but as I said earlier, due to this approach you are ending up with a code which is a lot more complex than needed (I said the same about the solution at jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/jgjHy - this was a little bit more elegant as it was a generic approach). I'm adding a link in my question description that reports a similar problem, but, unfortunately, I'm not happy with this solution (I'm not trying to be picky, I'm just looking for an elegant/reliable solution).

Comment: Ok, be sure to take a look at the google libraries for dynamic loading: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Introduction

Comment: I took a look at the Google API but, again, I'm quite reluctant in adding a new API just to achieve such a simple task (calling functions from scripts that are dynamically loaded). I was hoping that there was a plain jQuery way for doing this. Still, I understand if there is no straightforward jQuery solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

You should use:

```
$(window).load(function()
```

It will wait for external content to be already loaded (e.g. images, fonts)

Answer (score 1):

The jquery `.ready()` function, starts as soon as the DOM hierarchy is completely loaded. This usually happens after all images have been loaded.  The reason that it does not wait until the scripts/css documents are loaded is because they are "linked" meaning they are loaded externally and then remain in cache while the main code is translated into a view-able page.

If the script you currently have in the `$document.ready(function{})` relies on external assets, use the `<body onload="function()">` or `$document.ready($document.load(asset),function{})` if you want to load specific documents/assets then the function or script.

The `<body onload="function()">` function is different from the `.ready()` function because the `.ready()` function waits for the DOM to be built (as I said earlier) and the `<body onload="function()">` function waits for the page, not the DOM, to actually start to load or render.  The `.load()` function is event more different, because it load assets, files, or even snips of code into the page.  Using this method, in theory would be good because then there should be no need to append anything to the body.

Greater information (and a more thorough explanation) can be found at http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and http://api.jquery.com/load/.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It's not clear to me how this helps in my situation. I hope I was clear with my question: my intention is to dynamically load a script (for example, from an Ajax request after the user clicked a link) and also have a piece of JavaScript code that uses the script (so this does not happen within the page first load - it can happen whenever the users decides to click a link). Here's an example: user clicks a click, an Ajax call is made, the output is "<script src='plugin.js'></script><script>//Call to plugin</script>" - this will fail as I mentioned in my initial question.